# AWS S3 - Public file access to EC2 thru URL

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS S3 for storing pdf files, docs and other files and running my Backend java application and front end react application on EC2.
My requirements,

1. EC2 backend application should have access to the S3 bucket for put and get objects using the API or the Java client
2. EC2 front end application should be able to access the objects using the S3 URL
3. EC2 back end application should be able to access the objects using S3 URL

Added IAM policy to get EC2 instance access to the S3 bucket and it works for put and get using the API.
For, accessing objects using S3 URL, enabled pUblic access, but limiting only to the front end domain, so that nobody else can access the URL directly and it will be only thru the Front end.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "http referer policy example",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Allow get requests originating from www.example.com and example.com.",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket-uat/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "aws:Referer": [
                        "http://www.example.com:9000/*",
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This is working as expected. Now, I am able to access the files using S3 URL only within the front end app and not outside the front end app.

Now, I need EC2 instance also access S3 objects using the URL. Not sure, How can I add EC2 instance access in this policy. My EC2 instance count can be changing from 2 to 5,6,.... So want to make it generic so that all my current and future backend EC2 instances can  access thru URL.

Comment: You would typically give an EC2 instance IAM access to the S3 bucket via an IAM role; you wouldn't do this through a bucket policy. Note that referer spoofing is real, so your referer condition is not security.

Comment: I have EC2 IAM access  to the S3 bucket and able to access using API. But, restricting the URL access to the domain alone, so, unable to access using S3 URL in EC2.

Comment: Why does the EC2 instance, which is presumably part of your backend, need access via custom domain URL?

Comment: I have other requirement where converting html to PDF for download and need to add the S3 file URLs so that the html to PDF utility will be able to download directly.

Comment: But you know what the custom domain URL is, even if you don't use it. You can easily transform `s3://mybucket/static/index.html` to `https://www.example.com/static/index.html` for presentation to a web client, as needed, no?

Comment: `Referer` does not protect you from anything. Its a merely an inconvenience to who ever wants to get your files outside of your fronted.

Comment: @Marcin, With Referrer, I am unable to access the file other than from my domain. Trying to understand why it is not secure.

Comment: because anyone can spoof a referrer header. Please check [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/example-bucket-policies.html#example-bucket-policies-use-case-4), which clearly explain in red color why you should not rely on referrer.

Comment: @Marcin, What is the best way to protect? My requirement is to let my Frontend access thru URL but nobody else? What is the best approach?

Comment: You need proper authorization and authentication system, e.g. through AWS Cognito, so that only logged in users can access your files.

Comment: @jarmod Everybody will be able to access with custom domain. I want only from my Front end app or from the EC2 instance.